# ChangeDetectionStrategy not wrk properly

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-changedetection

I am using ionic 2

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="messagesholder" 
      *ngFor="let chat of chatval | orderby:'[date]'; let i = index;let first=first;let last = last;">
           {{last ? callFunction() : ''}} 

       <div *ngIf="chat.sender == currentuser || chat.receiver == currentuser" >
       {{checkdate(chat.date)}} 
       <p class="chat-date"  id="abc" #abc>{{msgdate | amDateFormat:'LL'}}</p>

     </div>
```

Here is my `checkdate` function:

```ts
checkdate(date)
  {
    var res = date.split(" ");
    var A=res[0];
    var local=localStorage.getItem('chatdate');
    this.msgdate="";
    if(local === undefined || local === null)
    {
      this.msgdate=A;
      localStorage.setItem('chatdate',this.msgdate);

    }
    else if(local !== undefined)
    {
      console.log(local != A);
      if(local != A)
      {

        this.msgdate = A;
         localStorage.setItem('chatdate',this.msgdate);
      }
    }

   }

    callFunction(){
    this.content.scrollToBottom(0)
  }
```

It's work. But I getting this error.

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'April 10, 2017'. Current value: ''.
```

Because I go this working by having these lines in my code :

```ts
import {  Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'page-chat',
  templateUrl: 'chat.html',
  
})
```

Now. I am getting no err msg. But content are not display.

I consoled the chatval.It's wrk fine.But its not display any value .

at the same time when I go to backbutton, content are display onesec.

If I remove the `ChangeDetectionStrategy`,

Again I getting this err msg

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'April 10, 2017'. Current value: ''.
```

Why use `ChangeDetectionStrategy`? UI values not display.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously you are modifyinng the state of the model after it was checkd. That you shouldn't do without binding to the variable. Remove

```
this.msgdate="";
```

Comment: I use also changeDetectorRef.markForCheck(); But still Not wrk.

Comment: The error will only disappear until you find the other way to change the variable before it was checked by the change detector. That's why I suggested to bind the variable so it gets updated value of the model once the component change it.

Comment: can u help me...?